# restful play api with mutual ssl

Tags: ssl, playframework, mutual-authentication

I have  a rest API built in Play! framework. This is on SSL layer. How to enable mutual SSL in this case. The clients calling my API will have their own public certificate. I have my own public certificate. But I am not sure how my play API can send certificates to authenticate client in this case.

Comment: When you say `client` do you mean anonymous users using a web browser. to access a public API. Or do you mean you have a known number of customers that you are limiting your API to?